# Specifying different eslint config files on command line

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintrc

How do you deal with using different config files for server-side (node.js) code and client-side code when linting with eslint? Do you specify differents arguments to eslint in your lint script in package.json? Do you have separate config files?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want different lint for those 2? Wouldn't it be a good idea having the same standard for the whole project?

Comment: I have an existing codebase written in legacy javascript. I'm slowly adding files to linting as I fix them up. Unfortunate reality of no one maintaining this part of the project full time.